# Why is the web application listed in the IIS of SharePoint's app servers?

Tags: 2016, web-application

I have a 3 tier SharePoint 2016 farm (1 web front end server, 1 application & 1 database)

Why does the IIS of SharePoint's app server show the web application? I think it should be listed only on front end? Is it right?

Furthermore, when I browse the web application from the front end with the front end server name , for example: http://frontend/ I get **file not found** but it is working with http://(app server name)

I think I am doing something wrong, how can create web application in 3 tier farm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct behavior. Part of the reason is to allow specific types of timer jobs to run on any server. The second reason would be to use a hosts file to direct the search crawler to crawl backend servers instead of crawling the frontend servers.

Comment: thanks, it's helpful, why I get file not found in the wfe server? is it normal? will I face this issue when browse the load balancer ip?